Data Cloud: Formula field to convert a text field to date field
I am streaming a data extension from Marketing Cloud to Data Cloud. The Data Extension has a field called SendDate, which is a text field.
It contains values like
09-29-2022
so
MM-DD-YYYY
I need to create a formula field in data cloud that translates this field into a date field. How do I do that? thanks

Have you tried playing around with the functions available in the formula field in data cloud? First you should set the Formula Return Type to 'DateTime'.
Assuming the date format you are using is consistent for all your subscribers, you should be able to use the following logic. It is however very rigid and can be optimized:
DATE(
RIGHT(sourceField['SendDate'],4),
LEFT(sourceField['SendDate'],2),
SUBSTRING(sourceField['SendDate'],3,5)
)

Alternatively, you should consider changing the text field in SFMC into a date field.
